# How to maximize the Nautilus open/save dialogue window?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, configuration

Env: Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 + ubuntu-desktop

The **Nautilus dialogue window** that is launched when Opening or Saving a file **can't be Maximized** any more:
[image]

Is there a configuration to **turn this on**?

Answer (score 0):

You are not referring to a nautilus window. You are referring to a GTK3 File - Open dialog, part of the standard GTK toolkit, which can be used by programs build on this toolkit.

That the "Maximize" option is grayed out indeed is unexpected, because, despite what the dialog suggests, it can be maximized. It may be worthwhile to file this issue with the developers if it has not yet been filed. Even in the most recent GTK versions, the "Maximize" option is grayed out.

You can quickly maximize the dialog using your Window manager's shortcut key to maximize a Window. In many desktop environments, the traditional shortcut key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> will allow you to toggle between maximized and restored. On the standard Ubuntu desktop, you can also use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. Use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to restore.

Comment: Thanks, but neither Alt+F10 nor SUPER+Up maximize the dialogue window. Just to clarify, so does Nautilus use the standard GTK toolkit, because it looks pretty similar.

Comment: Strange, it does for me, however on Gnome 40. Will check on 20.04.